# Is the solution to an inhomogenous equation for an equation Ax = b, a translation of the null space of A?

Tags: linear-algebra

If we have a matrix A, assuming the equation Ax = b is consistent and A is non invertible, then when put into vector parametric form we would get an equation along the lines
$x_n * v_n + x_k + v_k... + b_{r}$ where $b_r$ is the row reduced form of vector b in the augmented matrix A

So then would the solution set to Ax = b just be the null space of A + $b_r$ or in other words the solution set of the homogenous equation Ax=0 with a translation of vector $b_r$?